# How to make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a datatable with dropdown filter for my project where I am popluating the dropdown menu dynamically from the table.
Everything works fine but I am seeing the following browser error.

> Incorrect use of  The label's for attribute
> doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from
> correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working
> correctly. To fix this issue, make sure the label's for attribute
> references the correct id of a form field.

What I have tried -
I assigned the ID to the select tag in JS by using counter variable, then wrapped the select labels in HTML with a label tag using the assigned ID hardcoded as the for attribute in label, but somehow I am still getting the error. What am I missing? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
```

Please see my complete code here.

https://live.datatables.net/finezici/4/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table-wrap').hide();
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    responsive: true,
mark: true,
stateSave: false,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect(table);
  $('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
    // show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
$('#table-wrap').show();
    table.columns.adjust();

    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });

 
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
    $('#table-wrap').hide();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select id="dd' + counter + '"><option value="">Select</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');

    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
           // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox" select id="table-filter">
<p><label for="dd1">Name:</label> <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd2">Postion:</label> <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p><label for="dd3">Office:</label> <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button"  id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <div id="table-wrap">
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ID.AI</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your labels work fine. Most likely you're getting the error because when the HTML is rendered, there are no selects (since they only get created by js after the document is ready).

Comment: Option 1. Get rid of the "for" and just append the selects inside the label. Option 2. Generate the labels and selects together.

Comment: Thanks. I am still new to HTML and Javascript. Is there a way you can give me an example of how I can do option 2?

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. I will update the page th example tomorrow.