# How to make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am reposting this question as I still did not figure out how to fix this. The previous post had  some responses but I am not sure how to implement it. Here is the link to my previous post - [How to make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256365/how-to-make-sure-the-labels-for-attribute-references-the-correct-id-of-a-form-f)

I am using a datatable with dropdown filter for my project where I am popluating the dropdown menu dynamically from the table. Everything works fine but I am seeing the following browser error.

Incorrect use of The label's for attribute doesn't match any element id. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form and accessibility tools from working correctly. To fix this issue, make sure the label's for attribute references the correct id of a form field.

What I have tried - I assigned the ID to the select tag in JS by using counter variable, then wrapped the select labels in HTML with a label tag using the assigned ID hardcoded as the for attribute in label, but somehow I am still getting the error. What am I missing? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

var select = $('Select'

Please see my complete code here.

https://live.datatables.net/datubino/6/edit

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    
    responsive: true,
    searching: true,
    
    columnDefs: [
            {
                target: 6,
                visible: false,
                searchable: true,
            }
      ],
    
    dom: 'ilfrt<"left-col"B><"toolbar"><"right-col"p>',

    fnInitComplete: function(){
           $('div.toolbar').html('<p>Custom tool bar!</p>');
         },
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5', className: 'mybutton',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            
        //  'colvis'
        ],
         
});
  buildSelect(table);
 
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
         
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );

  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
  });
});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value="">select me</option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    if ( column.index() === 0 ) {
      var filteredNames = column.data().unique().toArray();
      ['Garrett', 'Test1', 'Ashton'].forEach((d) => {
        if (filteredNames.includes(d)) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
        }
      });
    } else {
      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
      });
    }

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
      // ** MY CHANGE **
      // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

    
    
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox">
<p>Name: 
  
  <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
  <button type="button" id="myInput">Filter Results</button>
</div>
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
  <th>&#160;</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Hidden Column</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
Test1</td>


            <td>test</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
            <td>Sys Architect</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett</td>
            <td>Director: fgghghjhjhjhkjkj</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
            <td>Director:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton</td>
            <td>Technical Authorjkjkjk fdfd h gjjjhjhk</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
            <td>Tech author</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you continuously replace `<select>` with a new `<select>` (which invokes DOM re-rendering unnecessarily), is there really any need to reassign `#id`s at all?

Comment: Can you please provide more details with an example. I am not sure what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Please correct the [mcve] so that we can see the error you want fixed.  As of now there are bigger problems with the code that make the entire example broken.  *`"Uncaught TypeError: table.search(...).draw is not a function"`*

Comment: I updated the code. Here is the new link to the code - https://live.datatables.net/datubino/6/edit